# Extract all fields from XML result using Google Geocoding API

Tags: xml, geolocation, geocoding

I am using the Google Geocoding API, specifically relying on the XML output format.  The code below loops through the array `$arrGeocodeSales` and for each row it retrieves the `$lat` and `$long`, which are then displayed in the table.

This code is working fine, but I would like to extend it so that I can extract more fields from the `$xml` result that is returned.  For example, some of the additional fields that I would like to extract from the $xml result are `formatted_address` and `postal_code`.  How can I modify the code below to extract the additional fields?

You can see an example of an $xml result here:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA&sensor=true)

Here is the code that needs to be modified.  I guess I don't understand how to work with the `SimpleXMLElement` that is returned.  Thanks for the help.

```
<table border="1" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Roll</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Lat</th>
  <th>Long</th>
  <th>MapSaleNumber</th>
  </tr>

<?php foreach ($arrGeocodeSales as $key => $value): 
    $address = $value['Address']."+".$value['Municipality']."+Ontario+Canada"; 
    $googleAddress = "https://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=".urlencode($address)."&output=xml";
    // Retrieve the URL contents
    $googlePage = file_get_contents($googleAddress);
    // Parse the returned XML file
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($googlePage);
    // Parse the coordinate string  
    list($lng, $lat, $alt) = explode(",", $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates);
 ?>
<tr>
  <td ><?php echo str_pad($row++, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); ?></td>
  <td ><?php echo $value['SingleRoll']; ?></td>
  <td ><?php echo $address; ?> </td>
  <td ><?php echo $lat ?></td>
  <td ><?php echo $lng ?></td>
  <td ><?php echo $value['MapSaleNumber']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the `SimpleXMLElement` result using the methods [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

You will need to iterate through the `address_component` elements to find one with the `type` element value you are interested in. Look for examples of other code using that API and you should be able to quickly figure it out.